# Using an MCP73831 charge controller with a BAS3007A Low VF Schottky Diode Array

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging

I'm working on a design that uses a custom USB charging cable that can be inserted into the device with either polarity. The +5V is rectified using a [BAS3007A](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/516907.pdf) Low VF Schottky Diode Array. This is then fed into an [MCP73831](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001984g.pdf) charge controller.

The issue I'm facing is that, due to the diode drop across the rectifier, the charge controller terminates charging before the battery is completely charged.

[image]
[image]

During charging I am measuring +4.36V on the output of the BAS3007A (net label: USB). Just before the controller switches to constant voltage charging, the current consumption drops to ~10mA with the status pin of the MCP73831 toggling on/off at about 1kHz.

If I apply a voltage of >4.5V after the rectifier, the same battery will resume drawing 200mA and the status pin will stay low until the charge sequence terminates as expected.

I believe it is because of this statement from the MCP73831 datasheet shown here:

[image]

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Any other charge controllers to recommend that will function with this low of an input voltage? Should I consider boosting the rectified voltage back up to +5V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using an H-Bridge wired as an active rectifier. By using the recommendation [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/444423/how-to-avoid-voltage-drop-when-using-full-bridge-rectifier-as-reverse-polarity-p) as inspiration, I bought a MOSFET Array 2 N and 2 P-Channel H-Bridge (DMHC3025) and wired it up as shown in the image below. This removed the voltage drop across the diode bridge and fix the inconsistent performance of my charging circuit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a step-up converter that will boost the 3.36V up to 5V. You need 5V to charge li-ion up to 4.2V

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo there. I'm measuring 4.36V which should be enough to charge a li-ion up to 4.2V